# How to output a window to a text file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, activation

I'm designing a batch file to first check if a copy of windows is activated (using the slmgr /xpr command) and if it isn't input a key to activate it. I have everything done except for the checking for activation as when you run the slmgr /xpr command, it outputs to a windows host script dialogue box and I can't figure out how to have that box output its text into a text file to use as a variable. Does anyone know how to do this/ has a better way?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could take a look at `%windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs`; see if you can make a copy that outputs to console or file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use cscript to output text from slmgr to the console.

```
cscript slmgr.vbs /xpr
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, you may just change `slmgr.vbs /dli` to `slmgr.vbs /xpr`.

It will automatically generate a text file saved to your `C:\` drive:

```
cscript c:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /dli > c:\slmgr_result.txt
```